# mat-menu theme color not changing

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have got my themes all working perfectly, but for some reason my mat-menu will only get themed on whatever default is called and not otherwise.
So for its theme to not be broken I have to call 
`@include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);`

right at the top of my styles.scss and then have my custom classes that I set, which my light is loaded by default as shown here:

```
import {OverlayContainer} from "@angular/cdk/overlay";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    title:string = "Callum.Tech";

    themeClass: string = "light-theme";

    overlay;

    constructor(
        private overlayContainer: OverlayContainer
    ) {
        this.overlay = overlayContainer;
    }

    setDarkTheme(): void {
        this.themeClass = "dark-theme";
    }

    setLightTheme(): void {
        this.themeClass = "light-theme";
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.overlay.themeClass = this.themeClass;
    }
}
```

Everything else will re-theme and work fine without calling the start include I mentioned but mat-menu will throw a fit and only use the first theme its fed on the site launching, and doesnt change with the rest of the theme.

Here is what it looks like with the dark theme called at the start of styles.scss and the light theme loaded like normal

[image]

And here is the dark theme chosen, but the dark theme not called at the start of styles.scss:

[image]

Comment: What version of Angular Material are you using? There's a breaking change in the latest version.

Comment: I believe i am using the latest version, should i downgrade for the time being? and to do so I just uninstall the package with npm and then install it again but set the version in the install line cmd?

Comment: Can you try running `npm ls @angular/material`?

Comment: Here is the whole result for clarity; https://i.imgur.com/CGuVdaL.png but the actual version of material itself lists as `@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the breaking changes for [`2.0.0-beta.11`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2.0.0-beta.11):

> overlay: Now that the Overlay is part of the cdk rather than Angular Material directly, the themeClass property has been removed. To add a class to the overlay for theming, you can do
>
> ```
> overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add('my-theme-class');
> ```

So, you can change your code as follows:

```ts
constructor(
    private overlayContainer: OverlayContainer
) {
    this.overlay = overlayContainer.getContainerElement();
}

toggleTheme(): void {
    if (this.overlay.classList.contains("dark-theme") {
        this.overlay.classList.remove("dark-theme");
        this.overlay.classList.add("light-theme");
    } else if (this.overlay.classList.contains("light-theme") {
        this.overlay.classList.remove("light-theme");
        this.overlay.classList.add("dark-theme");
    } else {
        this.overlay.classList.add("light-theme");
    }
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.toggleTheme();
}
```

Comment: You are correct but for all aspects of the theme to properly change I had to call the classList.add function under each setTheme() void like so; so maybe edit your answer for future users to clarify `https://i.imgur.com/JDWvB3y.png`

Comment: **Edit** I console logged the classList and it doesnt add the same class so adding it in every call seems fine Or can I just simply add the classes and then switch them with pure text after, for my current predicament it works fine but id imagine it might cause speed-related issues in the future or repeating of code